# Connecting to AWS IoT Websocket without MQTT client

Tags: websocket, mqtt, aws-iot

I have a client application which runs in the browser which I can't change the implementation of to implement an MQTT client such as [mqtt on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#browser).

The code in the library is as follows and allows me to pass in a socketUrl

```
const ws = new WebSocket(socketUrl)
```

I have tried generating a presigned URL for IoT, which seems to work in terms of authenticating (i.e. no Unauthorized response) but I get a 426 Upgrade Required response.

I believe I'm correct in saying that if it were working it'd reply with a 101 Switching protocols but without knowing much about MQTT i'm unsure if this is not happening because I'm doing something wrong or because I'm not using MQTT.

I'm generating a signed URL using the below code (I'll switch to Cognito Identities if I get this working rather than using the fixed key/secret)

```
const v4 = require('aws-signature-v4')
const crypto = require('crypto')

const socketUrl = v4.createPresignedURL(
  'GET',
  'myioturl.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  '/mqtt', // tried just /mytopic, too
  'iotdevicegateway',
  crypto.createHash('sha256').update('', 'utf8').digest('hex'), {
    'key': 'removed',
    'secret': 'removed',
    'protocol': 'wss',
    'region': 'us-east-1'
  }
)
```

The [protocols page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html) in the iot documentation seems to suggest that if I point at /mqtt I'm indicating I'll be using MQTT.

> mqtt Specifies you will be sending MQTT messages over the WebSocket protocol.

What does this mean if I just specify /foobar? Should I be able to connect to the socket but not using MQTT?

There are quite a few unknowns for me so I'm struggling to work out if it should work at all, and if so, which bit am I doing wrong.

Comment: This won't work, you have to use MQTT over websockets, you can't just connect and make up your own protocol because the AWS will expect MQTT.

Comment: Ok, that's one bit most likely answered, cheers. Any idea why I can't connect to the web socket server using the above, i.e. why don't I get a 101? Presumably this is the standard bit of connecting to a websocket then I use MQTT to send messages through the socket?

Comment: Does it really matter, you are going to have to use MQTT if you want to connect via websockets, so you might as well use a proper client, there is no point trying to implement your own.

Comment: Yes because I am looking to understand whether or not I can connect to the web socket server. I am also trying to understand whether or not the 
 reason I cannot connect is because there is something which is part of the MQTT protocol which is key to connection or if I should be able to connect but then not communicate. Furthermore the library attaches observables to the websocket connection so it's possible that I can send and receive MQTT once i've managed to connect, if I can connect. I can't change the way i connect but i can change the way i send messages perhaps.